# Fitting commutative Poisson distribution in python doesn't seem correct

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit my data with CDF Poisson distribution. I used scipy.stats.poisson

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.stats import poisson
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_to_fit = np.array([[ 3.839     ,  0.01818182],
       [ 3.9158    ,  0.05454545],
       [ 3.9542    ,  0.07272727],
       [ 4.0309    ,  0.09090909],
       [ 4.1845    ,  0.12727273],
       [ 4.2613    ,  0.14545455],
       [ 4.2997    ,  0.16363636],
       [ 4.6836    ,  0.18181818],
       [ 4.7604    ,  0.2       ],
       [ 4.8755    ,  0.23636364],
       [ 5.1826    ,  0.25454545],
       [ 5.3746    ,  0.27272727],
       [ 5.4514    ,  0.29090909],
       [ 5.7201    ,  0.30909091],
       [ 5.7585    ,  0.32727273],
       [ 5.8737    ,  0.36363636],
       [ 5.9888    ,  0.38181818],
       [ 6.0272    ,  0.4       ],
       [ 6.7183    ,  0.41818182],
       [ 6.8334    ,  0.43636364],
       [ 6.9486    ,  0.47272727],
       [ 7.2557    ,  0.49090909],
       [ 7.9083    ,  0.52727273],
       [ 7.9467    ,  0.54545455],
       [ 8.0619    ,  0.56363636],
       [ 8.1771    ,  0.58181818],
       [ 8.2538    ,  0.6       ],
       [ 8.5226    ,  0.61818182],
       [ 8.6761    ,  0.63636364],
       [ 9.2904    ,  0.65454545],
       [ 9.4439    ,  0.67272727],
       [ 9.4823    ,  0.69090909],
       [ 9.5975    ,  0.70909091],
       [ 9.6743    ,  0.72727273],
       [ 9.8662    ,  0.74545455],
       [ 9.9814    ,  0.76363636],
       [10.4037    ,  0.78181818],
       [10.826     ,  0.8       ],
       [10.9412    ,  0.81818182],
       [11.1715    ,  0.83636364],
       [11.7089    ,  0.85454545],
       [11.9777    ,  0.87272727],
       [12.0545    ,  0.89090909],
       [12.5535    ,  0.90909091],
       [12.5919    ,  0.92727273],
       [13.6285    ,  0.94545455],
       [14.1275    ,  0.96363636],
       [14.9337    ,  0.98181818],
       [15.164     ,  1.        ]])

# fit here
ppot, _= curve_fit(poisson.cdf, data_to_fit[:,0], data_to_fit[:,1], p0 = 0.1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(data_to_fit[:, 0], data_to_fit[:, 1], 'bo', label = "data", alpha = 0.5)
ax.plot(data_to_fit[:, 0], poisson.cdf(data_to_fit[:, 0], ppot), 'b--', label = 'CDF Poisson fit')
plt.show()
```

[image: This is what I got:]

I am not sure which step goes wrong because the fitting doesn't seem correct intuitively. I think a fit should be "smooth" whereas my result is not the case.                ....

Comment: Could you show all your inputs? I assume you use `scipy`'s `curve_fit`? Where is `poisson.cdf` coming from?

Comment: of couse, it's `from scipy.stats import poisson from scipy.optimize import curve_fit` So, it is a scipy's function.

Comment: Please add also the import for `matplotlib` and I think you also use `numpy` for the `data_to_fit`. Ideally one can just copy&paste the code and it runs as it is..

Comment: The [cumulative Poisson function must be stepwise because it only takes integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution). What may surprise you is that it does not show perfect steps - that is because you evaluate it on your original, discrete x-values, not on [evenly spaced x-values over this interval](https://imgur.com/a/0yh6S87).

Comment: @Mr.T Thanks for pointing it out. So, I guess even the fitting works on evenly spaced x-values over this interval, it is not a good fit. Does it mean I choose a wrong function? My x-values represent the radius of a circle, as the radius increase, items fall inside the circle also increase->that's my y-values. So y is an accumulated, after normalization, y always end up at 1. Do you have any idea what function should I fit for?

Comment: @Cleb My apologies, it's complete now.

Comment: @Mr.T Alright. Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried another function :

[image]

The above numerical result was obtained thanks to linear regression (non iterative method) as explained in : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales

[image]

For more accuracy, use non linear regression (iterative starting with the above values of parameters).